# Where Catalyst stores applist for switchable graphics?

Tags: amd-catalyst, switchable-graphics

I cannot add an app to the list to manually set it to high performance (Radeon instead of Intel HD). When I browse for an exe, nothing happens, the list is still empty. So, maybe I can edit some .cfg or .ini?

**UPDATE**

This is not my machine, but an example of what I'm looking to do: the list with iexplore.exe is what I meant. When I click 'Browse' and choose any exe (Portal2.exe, for instance) nothing happens. The list is empty, so I cannot set mode for Portal2.exe.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes the lists don't appear (not necessarily with Catalyst but generally) due to permission issues! Do you have full permission of the machine/software and OS etc?

Comment: Yep, I'm admin and UAC is turned off. What more permissions should I have?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by app list in the Catalyst please? This may help

Comment: Please see my update. I've attached a screenshot.

Comment: +1 for a better question. If you don't have an answer within 8 hours, I will check on my home PC.

Comment: Right, I'm trying to help,but I can't find the menu for switchable graphics any where

Comment: Did you installed the latest drivers?

Comment: @HashiramaSenju Oh, that old story... Lol, Acer messed up the drivers. On their own site. 2 files were swapped. And no warnings or errors that the driver is wrong for this device. As we programmers say, there are no perfect hardware solutions a programmer can't spoil with ugly firmware, drivers or bundled applications.

Comment: @noober Just checking lol =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking around in the appdata and I found this :

```
C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\ATI\ACE\APL\GpuAffinities.xml
```

This is how the xml is built up :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customisations Content="User" Format="1">
  <applications>
    <application Title="Google Chrome" File="chrome.exe">
      <use Area="PXDynamic">HighPerfGPUAffinity</use>
    </application>
    <application Title="Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2013" File="wdexpress.exe">
      <use Area="PXDynamic">HighPerfGPUAffinity</use>
    </application>
    <application File="iw4m.exe">
      <use Area="PXDynamic">HighPerfGPUAffinity</use>
    </application>
    <application Title="Skype" File="skype.exe">
      <use Area="PXDynamic">HighPerfGPUAffinity</use>
    </application>
  </applications>
</customisations>
```

I didn't test it but I guess you can simply add your programs there!

Greetings